# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer, which means?

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am working with Flask, making an integration to inventory identity access to GCP services. In my service I have a GCP API that will rotate the list of existing buckets to a project id (I have 1548 projects). In local it works without problem, but in a productive environment it returns the error

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

```
File "/app/app/resources/decorators.py", line 21, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/app/resources/decorators.py", line 68, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/app/blueprints/jobs/views.py", line 86, in gcp_group_members_inventory
    app.gcp_jobs_controller.gcp_group_members_inventory()
  File "/app/app/gcp/controller/jobs_controller.py", line 391, in gcp_group_members_inventory
    buckets_policy = self.buckets_policies_inventory(project['id'])
  File "/app/app/gcp/controller/jobs_controller.py", line 359, in buckets_policies_inventory
    buckets = self.main_controller.get_all_buckets_by_project(project_id)
  File "/app/app/gcp/controller/controller.py", line 918, in get_all_buckets_by_project
    buckets = self.service.get_all_buckets_by_project(project_id)
  File "/app/app/gcp/service/service.py", line 333, in get_all_buckets_by_project
    response = self.http.request(URL.format(project_id), method='GET', headers=self.headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 173, in new_request
    resp, content = request(orig_request_method, uri, method, body,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 280, in request
    return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1724, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1396, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/external_httplib.py", line 85, in httplib_getresponse_wrapper
    response = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 268, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 567, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 385, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(nbytes, buffer)
```

to try to fix it, I put a try except in the API response but it still does not respond:

```
    def get_all_buckets_by_project(self, project_id):
        URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project={}'
        try:
            response = self.http.request(URL.format(project_id), method='GET', headers=self.headers)
        except ServiceConnectionError as e:
            logger.error(("Error getting buckets: {}".format(e)))
            raise
        if '200' in response[0]['status']:
            json_resp = json.loads(response[1])
            if "items" not in json_resp.keys():
                raise ResourceNotFoundException('Buckets info not found')
```

is it possible that there is another solution? or the error can come from where? I was thinking if it can be something extra that I have to add in the Dockerfile, since I have it this way with an environment variable:

**ENV TIMEOUT=50000**

Comment: Connection reset means the other side closed the connection for some reason. As a test, add the query parameter `maxResults=10` to your request to see if that changes behavior. API [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list).